# How to execute a task immediately after adding to Schedule Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cron, schedule

I have next code:

```
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    $schedule->command(TaskCommand::class, [$task->id])->hourly();
}
```

I add this tasks dynamically.

**How to execute a task immediately after adding to schedule and after that to execute the task every hour?**

Comment: Will artisan do the job? Run command from CLI. You can also add it to your deploy script.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach should be done in scheduler, look at the code

In `app/console/kernel`

```
    namespace App\Console;

    use DB;
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands = [
            //
        ];

        /**
         * Define the application's command schedule.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
         * @return void
         */
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->call(function () {
                foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                    $schedule->command(TaskCommand::class, [$task->id]);
                }
            })->hourly();
        }
    }
```

Then you need to switch it on the server by command:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Good luck!

Comment: But the above code will only run dynamically added task after one hour. Schedule need to execute a task immediately after adding the task to database.

Comment: When I add some a task to `$tasks`, would the schedule executes this task immediately or only in the next hour?